# How to read QR codes with colors using zxing in kotlin and Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, qr-code, zxing

I'm using zxing in kotlin to read QR codes, and it works great, however I want to read QR codes with colors and it doesn't work, only black and white, how to do this?

this one reads it well,

[image: black and white QR code]

this cannot be read,

[image: color QR code]

> CaptureActivityPortrait.kt

```
class CaptureActivityPortrait: CaptureActivity() {
}
```

> build.graddle

```
implementation("com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:4.3.0")
```

> AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="co.edu.ut.jrbustosm.calina"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.zxing.client.android" />
    ....
    <application
        ....
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        ....
        >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            ....
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            tools:replace="android:screenOrientation"
            ....
            >
        ....
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".CaptureActivityPortrait"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            android:stateNotNeeded="true"
            android:theme="@style/zxing_CaptureTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

> AnyFile.kt

```
val scanLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
    contract = ScanContract(),
) { result ->
    if (result.contents != null) {/*do something with result*/}
}

val scanOptions = ScanOptions()
scanOptions.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(ScanOptions.QR_CODE)
scanOptions.setOrientationLocked(true)
scanOptions.setPrompt("Reading QR code")
scanOptions.setBeepEnabled(false)
scanOptions.setCaptureActivity(CaptureActivityPortrait().javaClass)

scanLauncher.launch(scanOptions)
```

Comment: If the colors of the qr code are only two, you can replace the two colors one with black and the other one with white and process it, then if it doesn't work swap the two colors and try again?


Is this a valid solution or maybe a good guess in the right direction?

Comment: @Mirco0 I think that it is a good solution, although I would not know how to implement it

Comment: https://github.com/yuriy-budiyev
I am using this library and checked on different Colored QR codes, and it's working fine for me also it has support for Jetpack compose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be by design in `zxing`, which is the de-facto standard.

You could however create some pre-processing of the image. The more colors you support the more error-prone the solution will be. (ie. if there are more than two colors, the likelyhood of getting it wrong increases).

You could use the `ColorMatrixColorFilter` in Kotlin and apply a `ColorMatrix` to turn the bitmap into grayscale, and try reading it again.

See example here:
[Manipulate Visual Effects With the ColorMatrixFilter and ConvolutionFilter](https://code.tutsplus.com/manipulate-visual-effects-with-the-colormatrixfilter-and-convolutionfilter--active-3221t#comment-45378)

If grayscale doesn't cut it, you will have to decide an arbitrary shade of grey – the threshold – that you will want to convert to white, and above it to black - to end up with the desired two colors only.

You could use ImageMagick via. [kmagick](https://github.com/MolotovCherry/kmagick) that has a oneliner for exactly this purpose:

```bash
convert <input> -threshold xx% <output>
```

See other answers for tweaking:

- [How to convert a photo to a black and white image by ImageMagick?](https://superuser.com/q/405686/103820)
- [Convert color photos of documents to good black-and-white (bitonal) images?](https://superuser.com/q/75373/103820)